# Import Python module with PyImport_ImportModuleEx for a gedit plugin

Tags: python, import, gedit

I'm learning Python and I try to use [Python Markdown](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) in a gedit plugin. Here's how my files are organized:

```
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest.gedit-plugin
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/__init__.py
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/__init__.py
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/preprocessors.py
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/OTHER_FILES
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/extensions/
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/extensions/__init__.py
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/extensions/headerid.py
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/extensions/OTHER_FILES
```

**Explication:**

My file `mytest.gedit-plugin` only contains minimal code to declare the plugin:

```
[Gedit Plugin]
Loader=python
Module=mytest
IAge=2
Name=My test
```

My plugin has its own subfolder (`mytest`). The file `mytest/__init__.py` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gedit
import markdown

class MyTestPlugin(gedit.Plugin):
    def __init__(self):
        gedit.Plugin.__init__(self)

    def activate(self, window):
        texte = "# Header 1 {#id}"
        print markdown.markdown(texte, extensions=['headerid'])
```

Finally, the folder `mytest/markdown` contains default Python Markdown code.

When I activate my plugin in gedit (*Edit > Preferences > Plugins*), output in the terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moi/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import markdown
  File "/home/moi/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    import preprocessors
  File "/home/moi/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/preprocessors.py", line 11, in <module>
    import markdown
ImportError: No module named markdown

** (gedit:8790): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'My test'
```

However, I successfully use Python Markdown outside gedit. For example, the following file works great when I run it in a terminal in the same location as the Python Markdown main folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import markdown

texte = "# Header 1 {#id}"
print markdown.markdown(texte, extensions=['headerid'])
```

I found that if I change `import markdown` in Python Markdown files for `import __init__ as markdown`, I can use Python Markdown without its extensions (`mytest/markdown/extensions/`), but anyway, it still doesn't work with my example:

```
/home/moi/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/mytest/markdown/__init__.py:114: MarkdownWarning: Failed loading extension 'headerid' from 'markdown.extensions.headerid' or 'mdx_headerid'
  warnings.warn(text, MarkdownWarning)
<h1>Header 1 {#id}</h1>
```

So, **my question** is how could I modify `import` for extensions, **or** how could I install Python Markdown in a local emplacement (so in `$HOME`, without root access) to be able to use Python Markdown in a gedit plugin?

Thanks a lot.

**Note:** I think gedit uses `PyImport_ImportModuleEx()` to load plugins, so that's why I put it in the title of my question.

---

**Edit 1:** 2 details: no root installation and possible to modify Python Markdown files.

**Edit 2:** Extensions are loaded with the following code in `mytest/markdown/__init__.py` (about line 525):

```
# Setup the module names
ext_module = 'markdown.extensions'
module_name_new_style = '.'.join([ext_module, ext_name])
module_name_old_style = '_'.join(['mdx', ext_name])

# Try loading the extention first from one place, then another
try: # New style (markdown.extensons.<extension>)
    module = __import__(module_name_new_style, {}, {}, [ext_module])
except ImportError:
    try: # Old style (mdx.<extension>)
        module = __import__(module_name_old_style)
    except ImportError:
       message(WARN, "Failed loading extension '%s' from '%s' or '%s'"
           % (ext_name, module_name_new_style, module_name_old_style))
       # Return None so we don't try to initiate none-existant extension
       return None
```

Maybe there's a way to import with relative path. I'm really beginner with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `markdown` without modifying it then you're going to have to put it somewhere where the Python library expects it, such as in `site-packages/`. Otherwise, you will have to modify it to use relative imports instead of absolute imports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If necessary, I can modify Python Markdown to be able to import extensions. I edited my question to note that I must use plugin without root access.

Comment: It is possible that gedit provides its own locations where it searches for modules; you can inspect `sys.path` to discover them.

Comment: I did a search about `site-packages/` and I found that from Python 2.6, a per user `site-packages` can be used. See [PEP370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/). It works very great.