# No module named markdown App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

My directory structure in app engine is like this :

```
project 
    app.yaml
    main.py
    lib
      markdown
        markdown_files
```

Markdown is being imported in `main.py` by `from lib.markdown import markdown` . At this point dev server is starting to give me the following stack trace. I am wondering what's going wrong here !? I do have an **init**.py in lib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2769, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2654, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 683, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1718, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1622, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1310, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "/Users/nomadali/jeeqs/git/src/jeeqs.py", line 26, in <module>
    from lib.markdown import markdown
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1845, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1717, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1660, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/Users/nomadali/jeeqs/git/src/lib/markdown/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    import preprocessors
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1845, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1717, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1660, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/Users/nomadali/jeeqs/git/src/markdown/preprocessors.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named markdown
INFO     2012-02-20 19:53:02,506 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 -
```

**Update1**

I believe this question is a dupe of [Import Python module with PyImport_ImportModuleEx for a gedit plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208369/import-python-module-with-pyimport-importmoduleex-for-a-gedit-plugin)

The answer:

> If you want to use markdown without modifying it then you're going to have to put it somewhere where the Python library expects it, such as in site-packages/. Otherwise, you will have to modify it to use relative imports instead of absolute imports.

**Update 2**
I resolved this issue by modifying my sys.path in app engine:

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'lib'))

Thanks to Murat for help,

Comment: Unless you have a lot third-party modules, it would be simpler to just remove the lib dir and put the markdown dir in the root of your project.  Then you don't need to edit your path at all.

Comment: I do have a lot of libraries actually.

Comment: You should add your answer as answer of your question and mark your answer as the right answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question is a dupe of Import Python module with PyImport_ImportModuleEx for a gedit plugin

The answer:

If you want to use markdown without modifying it then you're going to have to put it somewhere where the Python library expects it, such as in site-packages/. Otherwise, you will have to modify it to use relative imports instead of absolute imports.

Update 2 I resolved this issue by modifying my sys.path in app engine:

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), 'lib'))

Thanks to Murat for help,

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be called `__init__.py` for that to work.

Adding the lib directory to the pythonpath also works.

> If you want to use markdown without modifying it then you're going to have to put it somewhere where the Python library expects it, such as in site-packages/

This is incorrect, app engine has its own import mechanism and only packages that are explicitly white listed are allowed to be imported via this method.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is for lib to be in your PYTHONPATH, the paths where Python looks stuff that you try to import. As you've discovered, one way to do that is to add lib to sys.path.

Creating an **init**.py file is not what you want, because that makes lib a package containing markdown. At that point, you should be able to do

```
from lib import markdown
```

although that's not the recommended way to do it.